# breezejs: sorting by client-side property

Tags: javascript, breeze

I retrieve a list of Customer entities that are displayed in a list.

But for each customer I also get the list of Order entities so that I can add a client-side property **mostExpensivePurchase** to each customer basically the amount of the most expensive order for each customer). I do that in the Initializer of the registerEntityTypeCtor method.

Ok, now I have my grid showing Customer information, including my **mostExpensivePurchase** values.

But my user should be able to sort and even to filter on this column. When I tried, I got the error : 
`[error] unable to locate property: mostExpensivePurchase on entityType: Customer:#Business.Entities`.

Note that the filtering and sorting are done using a breeze query that is executed **locally only**. It would not make sense to execute it on the server since the property only exists on the client-side

I guess that error occurs because the metadata don't contain any info about that property.

How should I make this work ?

Side note: getting the list of Orders for each Client is obviously not good practice, but this was to illustrate my issue. And my list will always be limited to 50 entities max.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort each customer's list of orders using the `sort` function:

```
customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    customer.orders.sort(function(orderA, orderB) { 
        return orderA.mostExpensivePurchase() - orderB.mostExpensivePurchase();
    });
});
```

The documentation for sort is [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) (assuming the customer entity's list of orders is a knockout observable array).  The documentation for sorting a regular javascript array is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).